# Set domain alias with Heroku

Tags: heroku

There is a facility in Openshift to assign alias using the command line tool:

```
rhc alias add myapp www.somwhere.com
```

Having to point a domain `www.somewhere.com`'s `CNAME` to `myapp-mynamespace.rhcloud.com` would be enough to make access to www.somewhere.com go to the Openshift app.

I want to know if there is a facility in Heroku for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is yes, https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

```
 $ heroku domains:add www.example.com
```